# Is there a generic way to read the multiline json in spark. More specifically spark?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a multi line json like this

> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e" }, "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 2, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 57.92947112575566 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 21.24542588206755 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 68.19567810587429 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 67.95019716560351 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 18.81037253352722 } ] }

This is just 1 line from the json. And there are other files too. I am looking for a method to read this file in pyspark/spark. Can it be independent of the json format?

I need the output in the form of "scores" as individual column, like scores_exam should be one column with value 57.92947112575566, score_quiz another column with value 21.24542588206755.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

YES.

Use multiline true option

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("multi.json")
```

You get below output.

```
+--------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|_id                       |class_id|scores                                                                                                                                            |student_id|
+--------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|[50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e]|2       |[[57.92947112575566, exam], [21.24542588206755, quiz], [68.1956781058743, homework], [67.95019716560351, homework], [18.81037253352722, homework]]|0         |
+--------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Add these lines to get

```
  val df2= df.withColumn("scores",explode(col("scores")))
      .select(col("_id.*"), col("class_id"),col("scores.*"),col("student_id"))

+------------------------+--------+-----------------+--------+----------+
|$oid                    |class_id|score            |type    |student_id|
+------------------------+--------+-----------------+--------+----------+
|50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e|2       |57.92947112575566|exam    |0         |
|50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e|2       |21.24542588206755|quiz    |0         |
|50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e|2       |68.1956781058743 |homework|0         |
|50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e|2       |67.95019716560351|homework|0         |
|50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e|2       |18.81037253352722|homework|0         |
+------------------------+--------+-----------------+--------+----------+
```

Note that we are using "col" and "explode" functions from spark hence, you need to do the following import inorder these functions to work.

from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

You can more on how to parse a JSON file with multiline on below page.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-json.html

Thanks

Comment: I tried this. Many people have answered this. But this is not working.

Comment: What error are you getting? Actually, the record you have provided is in a single line and I was able to process it and generate output specified on my comment.

Comment: Sorry, I Didn't mean the error but I need the output in the form of  "scores"  as individual column, like scores_exam should be one column with value  57.92947112575566, score_quiz another column with  value 21.24542588206755

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is specific to this json. I wonder if there is a generic way to parse this type of json. This answer is great for this json but can we generalize it.

Comment: I've tried but it's not possible generic solution as it gets very complicated. May be post another question with the right statement, someone will answer