# Reading a multiple line JSON with pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I can't manage to read a JSON file in Python with pyspark because it has multiple records with each variable on a different line.

Exemple :

```json
{
  "id" : "id001",
  "name" : "NAME001",
  "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME001"
}
{
  "id" : "NNI002",
  "name" : "NAME002",
  "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME002"
}
{
  "id" : "NNI003",
  "name" : "NAME003",
  "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME003"
}
```

I want to load it as such :

```
+------------+------+-------+
|   firstname|    id|   name|
+------------+------+-------+
|FIRSTNAME001| id001|NAME001|
|FIRSTNAME002|NNI002|NAME002|
|FIRSTNAME003|NNI003|NAME003|
+------------+------+-------+
```

I got errors if I try `spark.read.json("file.json")`.

And when I use`spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("file.json")` I got only the first record :

```
+------------+-----+-------+
|   firstname|   id|   name|
+------------+-----+-------+
|FIRSTNAME001|id001|NAME001|
+------------+-----+-------+
```

I can read it with `spark.read.json("file.json")` if I put every records in there own line :

```json
{    "id" : "id001",    "name" : "NAME001",    "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME001"  }
{    "id" : "NNI002",    "name" : "NAME002",    "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME002"  }
{    "id" : "NNI003",    "name" : "NAME003",    "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME003"  }
```

But as I got 10M lines, it's not realy an option.

If any one got ideas to help me I would really appreciate.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have to add that your JSON string isn't valid JSON, there should be commas between the objects (there should be commas between { and }), and it is missing [ and ], too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a generic way to read the multiline json in spark. More specifically spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210389/is-there-a-generic-way-to-read-the-multiline-json-in-spark-more-specifically-sp)

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Yeah I know... but it's the file I get from the provider and they not gonna fix it...

Comment: @samkart Thanks for the link, I tried it but the explod function doesn't work, the result of my multiline are not arrays

Comment: you wouldn't need explode if you don't have arrays. just use part of the answer that reads the file.

Comment: @Steuv - solutions need to posted as an *answer* - not as an edit to your question. Please fix this.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Done. Didn't wanted to take credit for the answer as it's not my original idea. But as it's the way to go I'll abide by the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Niveditha S and @blackhorse0101 pointing bad JSON formating made me search for a way to correct the formating on a very large file.

Here is the code I used to correct the file in few seconds.

(take note that I use `nest_asyncio` as I'm in a Jupyter Notebook, you can use only aiofiles for a python script)

```py
import aiofiles
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

async def process_file(input_file, output_file):
    async with aiofiles.open(input_file, mode='r') as f:
        content = await f.read()

    # Add ',' after '}' if there is none
    lines = content.split('\n')
    for i in range(len(lines) - 1):
        if '}' in lines[i] and lines[i].strip().endswith('}') and not lines[i+1].strip().startswith(','):
            lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip() + ','
    
    # Remove last ','
    last_line = lines[-2]
    if last_line.endswith('},'):
        lines[-2] = last_line.rstrip(',')

    content = '\n'.join(lines)
    
    content = '[' + content + ']'
    
    async with aiofiles.open(output_file, mode='w') as f:
        await f.write(content)

input_file = 'file.json'
output_file = 'file_corrected.json'

await process_file(input_file, output_file)
```

Then `spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("file_corrected.json")` to read the corrected file

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because the input is not a valid json.
Your input should have been like this for your code to work fine.

```
[{
  "id" : "id001",
  "name" : "NAME001",
  "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME001"
},
{
  "id" : "NNI002",
  "name" : "NAME002",
  "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME002"
},
{
  "id" : "NNI003",
  "name" : "NAME003",
  "firstname" : "FIRSTNAME003"
}]
```

Now this will work.

```
spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("file.json")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know the file is not correctly formated but it's the output I get from the provider and they're not gonna fix it... I didn't manage to find an efficient way to correct the formating on 10M lines. Just loading the file it self in memory takes more than an hour and I get 2 update of that file a day... So correcting the formating is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Aha...I understood you. I will try to provide best solution for your.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solution well find you.

To read a JSON file in Python with PySpark when it contains multiple records with each variable on a different line, you can use a custom approach to handle the file format. Here is a potential solution:

Read the file using the textFile() method to load it as an RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset). This will allow you to process each line individually.

lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file.json")
Use the map() function to transform each line, ensuring that each line is a single JSON object. You can achieve this by appending a comma (,) at the end of each line except the last line, effectively concatenating all the lines into a single JSON array.

```
import json

processed_lines = lines.map(lambda line: line + "," if not line.endswith("}") else line)
json_array = "[" + processed_lines.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b) + "]"
Convert the JSON array string back to an RDD using parallelize().

json_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json_array])
Use the read() method to read the JSON data as a DataFrame.

df = spark.read.json(json_rdd)
If necessary, select the desired columns from the DataFrame to obtain the desired output.

output_df = df.select("firstname", "id", "name")
output_df.show()
```

This approach processes each line individually and concatenates them into a single JSON array, which can be read into a DataFrame using spark.read.json(). By applying these steps, you should be able to parse the JSON file with multiple records on different lines and obtain the expected output.

Note: Keep in mind that processing large JSON files can be memory-intensive. Ensure that your Spark cluster has enough memory to handle the size of the file. Additionally, consider partitioning the data or using other optimization techniques if needed.

Comment: I like your idea to correct the bad formating, but unfortunally it takes more than an hour to do the reduce part and I receive 2 updates of the file a day so it's not working for me but clearly it will help others finding this page.